# hmac-sha256 support

Tags: ssh, hmac

From linux when execute ssh -c 3des -m hmac-sha256, error message 'unknown mac type-hmac256' is thrown. can someone please suggest me how to use hmac256 algorithm?
Any ssh client which supports hmac-sha256?

Comment: The SSH protocol doesn't support any 256-bit MAC algorithms yet.

Comment: can you share link where it is mentioned?

Comment: [RFC4253, section 6.4](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-6.4)

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another link that says - it has added support for SHA-2 family of secure hash algorithms.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6668
You can consider checking this with OpenSSH 5.9 per this link
http://cvs.openbsd.org/openssh/txt/release-5.9